# Architecture for Amazon Web Services / AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We're planning to upgrade our AWS to more recent hardware. The current setup is EC2 Classic intance-based servers attached to volumes which contain all of the apps data. The concept behind it is that if one of the instance-based servers were lost, we could recreate the server from its AMI and re-attach the volume with the data an be up and running again.

As we upgrade to servers as EC2/EBS volumes (and into a VPC), the risk of server being destroyed is mitigated. Is it worth it just keep all the apps on the new servers and forget about keeping them on attached volumes?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: if you're using EBS in the new setup, then those are volumes attached to your instance. Are you asking about _additional_ attached volumes?

Comment: No, I'm just wondering if we should dump the attached volumes and load everything onto the server.

Answer (score 1):

The strategy we used when moving to VPC was to make as few changes as possible. Just launch new servers in a public VPC, nothing else. If you start to change too much at once and encounter a problem, it will be harder to identify the source of the problem because there are so many changes.

For that reason, I recommend keeping your current setup. There might be advantages of a new architecture, but wait until after you've safely migrated to VPC.